# How to override css styles when @extend from other class in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have scss code:

```
.a {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.b {
    @extend .a;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The compiled css looks like:

```
.a, .b {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.b {
    height: 200px;
}
```

when I apply this style the dom `<div class="a b">` will have the height of `100px` instead of `200px`. How can I make the css take the height 200px in this case?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It looks like `.b` already overrides the height of `.a`.

Comment: `.b` already overrides the `height`. What exactly was your point?

Comment: Then why not change directly in .a selector: .b {   @extend .a; }  and .a {  height: 200px;}

Comment: sorry for confusing, I have rephrased my question

Comment: Then which selector in most below this will apply this is general rule for any CSS file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then which selector in most below this will apply this is general rule for any CSS file.

Height will be `<div class="a b">` 200px;

```
.a {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    }   
.b {
    @extend .a;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Height will be `<div class="a b">` 100px;

```
.b {
    @extend .a;
    height: 200px;
}
.a {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Always height will be `<div class="a b">` 200px order dose not matter;

```
.a {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    &.b {
       height: 200px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This already does exactly what you want.

You might have the `.b` above your `.a, .b` then the latest style wins.

Read up on [cascading order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order)

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

```css
.a, .b {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.b {
    height: 200px;
}

/* ignore */
div{
  background-color: red;
}
body{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<span>|</span>
<div class="b"></div>
<span>|</span>
<div class="a b"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your question is right, It cannot be overridden like

```
.a, .b {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Because, it will apply `width: 200px;` to both `.a` and `.b`, what you need is to apply `width: 200px;` to `.b` only, right? In that way, the code you provided works perfect already.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a wrapper

```
.a {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.b {
    @extend .a;
}

.wrapper .b {
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'><div class='b'> XXX </div></div>
```

You can also use `!important`.

```
.a {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.b {
    @extend .a;
    height: 200px !important;
}
```